# Meteor reactive search bar with all results when unfocused

Tags: javascript, mongodb, meteor

I'm trying to implement a simple search option in my meteor project, but I've never had any experience with search bars at all. My template is currently listing all elements from a collection and I'd like my search bar to aggregate those results reactively.
I've been able to achieve that result with the easy search package but this is where my issue begins.
 Using easy search, unless I start typing in the search box I can't get any results to show. The problem with external packages is that they're really hard to edit and I have no idea how to add an option like that or a custom search bar instead.
I've tried following the search source package but the tutorial is explained for that particular package search and I didn't know how to adjust it to my project.
So once again. I want to add a search bar to my list, but I want all the elements to be listed if I'm not using it and none if there weren't any matches.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check out [this meteorpad](http://meteorpad.com/pad/PDdgSnR4PZz9X3hWG/Search) I put together. Full code below:

### client/main.html:

```
<body>
  {{> main}}
</body>

<template name="main">
  <div><input id="search" placeholder="Search"></div>

  {{> foodList}}
</template>

<template name="foodList">
  <ul>
    {{#each foods}}
      <li>{{name}}</li>  
    {{/each}}
  </ul>
</template>
```

### lib/collections.js:

```
Foods = new Mongo.Collection('foods');
```

### client/app.js:

```
Template.foodList.helpers({
  foods: function () {
    var regexp = new RegExp(Session.get('search/keyword'), 'i');
    return Foods.find({name: regexp});
  }
});

Template.main.events({
  'keyup #search': function(event) {
    Session.set('search/keyword', event.target.value);
  }
});
```

### server/app.js:

```
Meteor.startup(function() {
  if (Foods.find().count() === 0) {
    Foods.insert({name: 'Blueberries'});
    Foods.insert({name: 'Strawberries'});
    Foods.insert({name: 'Steak'});
    Foods.insert({name: 'Eggs'});
  }
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that helped a lot! It seems like the meteorpad is broken though..

Comment: The meteor pad no longer exists?